# Cookies not set from chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, microsoft-edge

Problem started today. I can't set httpOnly and SameSite None attributes from any browser I use chrome edge.. So I can't reach cookies from localhost
[image]

I tried old solutions in the internet but many of the flags(Partitioned cookies flag) does not exists on settings anymore and it happened after new chrome version  I tried Firefox either but even if I make httpsOnly false Secure false and SameSite None it still can't reach cookies on localhost

I tried using proxy too but it didn't worked either I don't know what should I do.
[image]

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the issue in latest Edge and Chrome Stable version. I think it's an issue as from the [official doc](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/application/cookies#edit), all fields except Size should be editable.

As Edge and Chrome are both based on chromium, I use Edge as example. I download Edge Beta version 123.0.2420.10 to test and the issue is fixed, which means this issue will be fixed in future version of Edge Stable. We can wait for the new release of Edge Stable. For now, you can download and use Edge Beta temporarily: [Download Edge Insider](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/download/insider?form=MA13FJ).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cookies with **SameSite=None** must also include the **Secure** attribute and be set over **HTTPS**.

I blogged here about how to troubleshoot and diagnose cookie problems here:
https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/